# Function to return Boolean is always returning true

Tags: php

I want to check if user is logged on site or not, so I made a function:

```
function isLogged()
{
    if($_SESSION['logged']=='1')
    {
        return true;
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']!=='1')
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On my site Im trying to induce function like this:

```
if('isLogged')
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
```

Even if $_SESSION['logged'] is set to 0 (I just checked by echo value), it returns "yes". What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `if('isLogged')` that's a string literal. Are you trying to call that function? Plus, make sure the session was started and that the session is "set".

Comment: get rid of `elseif` just use `else` and `'isLogged'` should be `isLogged()`.

Comment: @DrKey thank you, how could I miss this :d

Comment: Just a Typo, its no further use, lets get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actual call the function, not check if the string returns true:

```
if(isLogged())
{
    echo 'yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you cleanup/refactor the `isLogged()` functionas well to get rid if the unnecessary `elseif`